# Localize string

Tags: ios, localization

I want to change my ios app's language. So I used string files to change into different languages. But my problem is when user close app (not minimixed), and re open the app how those settings persist. Is it possible using this `Localize` string files. If not how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the system locale to change the language or some custom setting?

Comment: no just keep a string file for required title and, refering the key values Im getting the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localization to change the app's language. A good tutorial for localization would be:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

If you insist on using string files for localization, I would warn you that apple automatically deletes an app’s preserved state when the user force quits the app.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't be forcing your user to pick a language. Instead, you should provide a list of supported languages, and let them choose themselves which language they want to use through System Preferences.

See the localisation guide here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html